# Child's layout of RelativeLayout with match_parent ant minHeight issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I have strange issue. I have LinearLayout which contains some fixed sized elements and one ReletiveLayout, which use remain space of parent space (weight=1). Simple layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_between_views"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/login"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="aneworld@gmail.com" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="pandora9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/login_button" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="100dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/support"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@string/support_number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/support"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/space_between_views"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I added minHeight parameter, for fix issues for small screens. But, if remain space of parent is smaller than this minHeight, **Forgot Password** child goes to top of parent, ABOVE flag is ignored. Why?

I know other way to make this working, but I just want to know why happens this.

I added screenshots for what:

Remaining space is bigger, so Forgot password is above support:
[image: Remaining space is bigger, so Forgot password is above support]

Remaining space is smaller, so Forgot password is top on parent:
[image: Remaining space is smaller, so Forgot password is top on parent]

Comment: if you have given a weight to RelativeLayout then change the android_layout_height="0dp" instead of match parent

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal, thanks, I fixed that. But this not fix this RelativeLayout issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what's wrong with this layout, but try enclosing all the other Views in a parent layout and assign that layout a weight as well. That should solve the issue.

Comment: You tell about parent's childs of RelativeLayout? Could you tell what weight I should assing?

Comment: What I meant was, all views above the RelativeLayout should be enclosed in a LinearLayout. Assign this LinearLayout a weight (say 1).  You can then edit this weight based on what height you want this layout to be.

Comment: Same issue remains. I think this is RelativeLayout problem. MinHeight change some internal parameters. I know a low of methods to fix this problem, I just to know why happens this.

Comment: Oh I just realised you're using a ScrollView. Any particular reason for that?
If you remove the ScrollView and try it the way mentioned above, it should work

Comment: Then I remove scrollView, RelativeLayout use only remaining space, minHeight is ignored. But I must use scrollview, otherwise I can't guarantee every user will see all content even with small phones.

Comment: If you use the weights properly, you'll definitely not need any ScrollView here. I'm assuming this is what the final UI is.

Comment: I need weight to fill remaining space, because I am using `android:fillViewport="true"` on ScrollView.